# Scroling speeding in Components Lwuit

Tags: scroll, lwuit

Most of the component in **lwuit** are scrolling slowly like TextArea or Container.

is it built-in in the component definition's? or can i control on speeding?

if so,how can i control them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWUIT spends most of its time in `Font.stringWidth`, wasting precious cpu cycles on basically the same strings again and again (with a new repaint after every scroll-step/focus change).

The solution is to subclass Font, add a `'String Width Pool'` that keeps track of, say, 30 strings at most and their widths. You then use this cache to return width of strings you're already aware of. This single change makes scrolling/flicking on the same devices much,much and much faster.

Implement it and let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Il look on the code in lwuit. But i don't see where to do what you say. I saw that we call only in function initRowString()

Comment: There already is a string width cache in LWUIT and in Codename One